# Commas before and/or after "because

Tags: grammar, commas

Which is proper grammar:

1. He argues that there is no binding contract, because, at any given time...
2. He argues that there is no binding contract, because at any given time...

Thanks so much!

Comment: Or, "He argues that there is no binding contract because, at any given time, ..." I hope someone can answer this question, but also with regard to the comma *before* "because," which I use only to disambiguate a statement like: "He is not here because he is wealthy" (Is he absent because he is wealthy, or is he here for a reason other than that he is wealthy?)

Comment: You should have included the rest of the sentence.  It appears that "at any given time" is being used as a "parenthetical", and such phrases are usually set apart with a beginning and an ending comma.

Answer (score 1):

Proper use of language is a reflection of whether a reader will be helped or hindered by the style. All of the proposed solutions above are more or less acceptable -- I wouldn't touch your grade on any of them. Still, looking over earlier comments I would say that the point about parentheticals is a useful thought. One way to check whether a form is a parenthetical is by setting it off with parentheses or an em dash:

> He argues that there is no binding contract (because[,] at any given time...)

> He argues that there is no binding contract -- because[,] at any given time...

Sure, those read fine -- except that I'd ditch the following comma as unnecessary. It seems to slow down reading without adding any information. However, be aware that **because** here is a *subordinating conjunction* leading to a dependent clause ("at any given time..."). Conjunctions of all sorts need not be surrounded by commas. So you don't need to precede *or* follow **because** with a comma. And yet if one of the clauses is rather long, then you should consider putting a comma in, to give the reader a rest. In this case you can argue it as a rest *or* as the introduction to a parenthetical. Everyone wins.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the purpose of a comma is a slight pause in your rhythm, a break between related but different parts of a sentence. Because of this, we would need an entire sample sentence for context.

Let's say "He argues that there is no binding contract because at any given time either side has a legal right to exit"; obviously without punctuation at all it's a run-on sentence.

> He argues that there is no binding contract, because at any given time, either side has a legal right to exit.

Here, you're breaking the sentence into three parts with the comma.  Putting a comma in front of `because` makes the initial part a statement of his argument, but without reason.  The rest of the sentence provides the reason (in two parts).

> He argues that there is no binding contract because, at any given time, either side has a legal right to exit.

By moving the comma over one word, the initial sentence fragment defines that this is *about* the reason rather than the reason just being an addition to his argument.

So there isn't a hard and fast rule based solely on the words, but the context and intent help define comma placement.  Also, it's fairly uncommon that a single word will be surrounded by commas.  This is typically the case only when it's a break-out word, often a descriptor, that the sentence doesn't require to make sense but the inclusion of which clarifies or further describes things.  For instance:

> Of all his shirts, the one in his favorite color, green, is the one he washes by hand so as to keep its color vibrant.

Green is a break-out, it further describes the previous fragment (his favorite color), but could be removed without causing the sentence to become nonsense.  Often, these are words that could also be presented parenthetically, but due to style choice or format requirements are surrounded by commas instead.  This works for one or two words, but longer parentheticals should not be surrounded by commas instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to insert a comma in the sentence. As the sentence stands a comma seems superfluous. You may need a comma after 'time' -- depending on the context. The following clause may or may not need a comma. As I said it depends on the context and unless you provide the third clause, saying you need a comma would be presumptuous because you don't.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence of yours that I have quoted below is not a run-on sentence. I recommend you do some more studying.

Let's say "He argues that there is no binding contract because at any given time either side has a legal right to exit"; obviously without punctuation at all it's a run-on sentence.

Comment: is there a way you could extend this into a slightly more general rule?

Comment: The subordinating conjunction because serves to join the two independent clauses. This is why I stated the sentence isn't a run-on sentence.